# Find the directory alphanumerically

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bunch of directories that I are named with the following time stamp format:

```
2013-12-04_18_12_40
2013-12-04_19_12_22
2013-12-04_19_46_45
2013-12-04_20_31_04
2013-12-04_21_04_54
2013-12-05_11_15_24
```

i.e. 
YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS

I want a bash script to CD into the latest directory. So in this case it would be

```
 2013-12-05_11_15_24
```

i.e. the latest directory will always be the biggest number.

How do I determine the latest directory in a nice way that can be used in a script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd "$(find . -print0 | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n' | tail -1)"
```

Comment: thanks. Couldyou explain what the print0, sort -z, the tr etc all do. Thanks.

Comment: won't this also check sub directories?

Comment: print0 puts null characters to separate files. with -z sort processes input looking at null characters. tr '\0' '\n' puts newlines instead of null characters. these are all for handling files with spaces is their name.

Comment: @BreakoBreako, you can add -maxdepth 1 to remove them

Comment: I thought the sort -z meant:   end lines with 0 byte, not newline

Answer (score 1):

Though generally it is not recommended to parse `ls`'s output but in this case you can probably do:

```
cd "$(ls -rd [0-9]* | head -1)"
```